# Removing part of a random string using sed or grep (Or any other regex solution)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have an XML File generated by a CMS that denotes what UI buttons should be displayed for a touchtable application. Please find below:

```
</GlobalMenu>
 <Buttons>
  <Button name="salford_121"/>
  <Button name="salford_197" title="SkillsWorkshop"/>
  <Button name="salford_121"/>
  <Button name="salford_190" title="Salford Students"/>
  <Button name="salford_121"/>
  <Button name="GlobalMenu.xml" title="Main Menu"/>
 </Buttons>
</GlobalMenu>`
```

When this file is generated I need to run a bash script that removes  `title="xxxxx"` leaving the `/>` at the end of each line. The title could have any sequence of  alpha numeric characters and symbols up to 80 characters long including spaces. I also need it to ignore lines with `title="Main Menu"` so not to delete the `go back` function of the menu that returns to the GlobalMenu.xml file. It would also be backed up to a custom.bak file.

Im trawling through any Regex tutorials, but Im finding it difficult to write something using sed or grep for changing RANDOM substrings, as these titles could be anything. Please forgive my noobness Ive only been at this for 5 days.

Comment: Edit your question to include the expected output given that input.

Comment: Is the `/` on the first `</GlobalMenu>`a typo/copy error? If you have XML, use XML tools rather than trying to use tools designed for text processing such as awk or sed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/ title="Main Menu"/!s/ title="[^"]*"//' file.xml

cat file.xml
</GlobalMenu>
 <Buttons>
  <Button name="salford_121"/>
  <Button name="salford_197"/>
  <Button name="salford_121"/>
  <Button name="salford_190"/>
  <Button name="salford_121"/>
  <Button name="GlobalMenu.xml" title="Main Menu"/>
 </Buttons>
</GlobalMenu>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the `.` special character, which matches anything.  However you want something more like `[a-zA-Z ]` to match a string containing only the alphabet and spaces (`.` is greedy).  If you want to include numbers as well, you can specify \d: `[a-zA-Z \d]`

```
/title="[a-zA-Z \d]"/g
```

I also tend to use [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) to double-check my search strings.

Comment: I can't think of any standard UNIX tool (sed, awk, or grep) that would do what you want with that regexp. Don't rely on some online regexp verifier as a regexp is useless out of the context of the tool you want to use it in.

Comment: A handy way to get non-greediness is to use the delimiter in a negated character class, as in `([^)]*)` to match everything between two parentheses, or `"[^"]*"` for quotes, instead of trying to guess what might be between the delimiters. It can still fail, though, when there is an escaped delimiter.

Comment: @EdMorton That is true, the various flavors of Regex *can* behave differently.  For the work that I do, the online is perfect as I happen to *also* be working in Javascript.

Comment: That's fine but what's the point posting an answer that will not work in any of the tools requested in the question? Just wastes everyone's time. btw - don't use `a-zA-Z`, use `[:alpha:]` instead for portability across locales, and the actual equivalent POSIX ERE using POSIX character classes for your answer would be `title="[[:alnum:][:blank:]]+"`

Comment: Thanks all your your timely and extremely helpful replies, I'll work on this today and get back to you.

Comment: OK so basically I need to use XML tools to remove these elements. If I needed to remove these entries using xml commands in a bash script file, what would my approach be?